# LED series and parallel connection 7S3P

Tags: led-strip

[image] using 21nos 3w led diode.  I am using 24v dc and 3amp supply. Connected 21x 3w led

Can I add another parallel connection to run 5v dc 0.16 Amp fan ?

Now I am using 3 x 4.7 ohm , 2W resistors, which are too hot from 24V.

Comment: A 16 amp fan??? I think you've mistyped that.

Comment: Can you first edit your word soup into full sentences? And what the &^&%&^ has that fan to do with the LEDs??

Comment: Sorry for answering too quick. @manas needs to define all assumptions on LED datasheet, power supply model, method of current control , thermal cooling before starting any design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- May be a solution if thermally matched.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWB6oP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- Add 0 in front of dot .16amp and capitalize Amp , and fan implies LEDs are hot but his problem is mismatched fan voltage and hot series R's that even fan cannot cool.
- best solution is use a better metal PCB heatsink for LED's and if necessary,  a fan to match supply voltage

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56119/discussion-on-answer-by-tony-stewart-ee-since-75-led-series-and-parallel-conne).